# FireDAC "unable to complete network request to host"

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac, isapi

The full error text is **Remote error: [FireDAC][Phys][FB]Unable to complete network request to host "dataserver16". Error writing data to the connection**. Now it seems that others have had this problem then once they sorted it, it went away, but I have the problem sporadically.

My Datasnap ISAPI.dll which contains the FireDAC Firebird connection, is running on an IIS server on a different machine to the one where the database is hosted (dataserver16) but on the same subnet. I know everything is configured correctly, because ***the application works to expectations about 70% of the time***! The other 30% of the time, my Datasnap client receives this error (as passed back from the dll).

Comment: Are you using any udf libraries? The Firebird server process stops unexpectedly after an exception in such libraries. You should definitely get a look into the firebird.log file on the server. It might hold further information.

Comment: I'm not using any UDF libraries. Thanks

Comment: Anything in the firebird.log file?

Comment: I see a lot of these: `DATASERVER16 (Server) Thu Jun 28 10:00:16 2018 INET/inet_error: read errno = 10054` but they don't correlate to the exact times the reported error occurs. I appreciate the help.

Comment: errno = 10054 is connection reset by peer, and is usually an indication the connections aren't closed correctly by the client, it is probably not related to your problem.

Comment: By adding a new ServermethodsUnit to the dll, I now have a way to allow a client to either use the DBX or the FireDac datamodule. The error is the same though.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it looks like there is a Network issue. If the Connection is Etablished and you can read and write Data to this connection it seams to be correct.

Have you tried to do a Ping from your Source System to the Target and log that Ping so you can See if the hole Connection to the Server disapears?

Open Commandwindow as Admin and Type:

```
Ping {TARGET} -t >> c:\ping.log
```

Than wait until the Error apears and check the Logfile if your Target was available the hole Time.

For more Help we need more Background Information, like Firebird Version or If you are able to reproduce the Error + Source Code how you set up your Connection.

Comment: Ping Time from IIS Server to dataserver16 is <1ms for 100 pings. I am rewriting my ISAPI.dll's datamodule to use DBX in place of FireDac now. Firebird 2.5

Comment: u might check mORMot - they have direct interface with low-level IIS for high performance. They have less emphasis on Firebird though

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I am posting my solution here. Perhaps others will gain benefit from this answer. The solution is to perform retries of the Firebird connection. The way I did it, is every TSQLQuery's BeforeOpen event handler is wired to the same method. This has improved reliability considerably (even if it slowed it down a little). The code for FireDAC is similar. Both DBX and FireDac work equally well here.

```
const
   retrycount = 3;

procedure TServerMethodsDBX.QueryBeforeOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  TryConnect(TSQLQuery(DataSet).SQLConnection);
  // ...
end;

procedure TServerMethodsDBX.TryConnect(SQLConn: TSQLConnection);
var
  i: Integer;
  Error: String;
begin
  i := 0;
  SQLConn.Close;
  while (not SQLConn.Connected) and (i < retrycount) do
  begin
    try
      SQLConn.Connected := True
    except
    on e: exception do
    begin
      Error := Error + ' ' + e.Message;
      Sleep(500);
      Inc(i);
    end;
    end;
  end;
  if i = retrycount then
    LogMessage('Tryconnect error: ' + Error);
end;
```